# is it possible to make `pip install -U` work for pip packages installed with git repos?

Tags: python, pip

I can do `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/foo.git@my_branch`. But then upgrade command like `pip install -U foo` will not work. I have to use `pip install -U git+ssh://git@github.com/myuser/foo.git@my_branch`. I wonder is there a way to setup the pip environment variable or config file can allow `pip install -U foo` to work.

Can I add github repo as additional package source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I add github repo as additional package source?

No. `pip install foo` means "install package `foo` from the index". The default index is PyPI.org. There is no way to use a VCS repository or a VCS hosting as an index.

You can simplify things by putting you package names from package indices and VCS URL(s) into a text file (usually called `requirements.txt`) and run

```
pip install -U -r requirements.txt
```